# What does Lucifer mean at the end of Constantine?

Tags: plot-explanation, constantine

At the end of *Constantine*, what did Lucifer mean when he said

> looks like somebody doesn't have your back anymore

when Gabriel went to smite Lucifer?

Answer (score 15):

He meant that God is not with Gabriel

Gabriel is trying to smite Lucifer with all his God-given might... just to be easily rebuked by Lucifer. So it is obvious from this, that God doesn't approve Gabriel's plan to bring hell on Earth.

Here is the script (italic parts spoken by Lucifer):

> Lucifer.
>   *This world is mine. ln time.
>
>   You, best of all of us, Gabriel...
>
>   ...should understand ambition.*
>
>   Son of perdition.
>   Little horn.
>   Most unclean.
>   *l do miss the old names.*
>
>   *Time to go home, son.*
>
>   l will smite thee...
>   ...in his honor.
>   *Looks like somebody doesn't have your back anymore.*
>
>   Father?